Difference in Cholesky Decomposition Results Between Julia and MATLAB
I'm translating a code from MATLAB to Julia and noticed differences in the results of the Cholesky decomposition, despite using the same input matrix.
In Julia, I used:
R = sparse(cholesky(K[perm, perm]).L)'

In MATLAB, I used:
R = sparse(chol(K(perm, perm)));

However, nnz(R) in Julia is 1404, while in MATLAB, nnz(R) is 1352. Exporting R from Julia to MATLAB gives nnz(Rjulia) = 1356.
Could this be due to numerical precision differences? How can I ensure consistent results between both environments?
K[perm, perm]= https://justpaste.it/gxful

Start with a smaller matrix, see what kind of differences you see. Look at the numeric values, you'll be able to answer your question of "Could this be due to numerical precision differences?".

If you multiply your matrix through by 3*5/0.005008047876602563 and divide by 256 or 512 then numerical QR codes might at least stand a chance. The matrix values appear to be integers divided by some random number or other (8386501?). ISTR Julia hands numerical matrix work over to LApack so you should get the same answer from that. My instinct is that Matlab is probably getting it wrong but whether or not LAPack/Julia is getting it right I wouldn't like to speculate. Rescaling and round so that the values are all exactly represented ought to help (and also keeping their magnitudes near 1).

I discovered that it has to do with both numerical precision and permutation. In Julia, I computed: R = sparse(cholesky(K).L)' without permuting it to better condition the matrix, and to my surprise, I got exactly the same result as in MATLAB, with a difference in the 18th decimal place.
